# Max number of UITabBar items allowed in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I currently have 8 UITabBar items, all of which are editable in the More view. My question is, what is the absolute maximum number of tab bar items allowed?

I understand 5 is the most that can be visible at one time; I'm looking for the most you can have period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a hard limit, as long as you don't run out of memory. I've used more than 20 in the past without any problems (although having many controllers means you should be really careful when managing memory, i.e. handling **didReceiveMemoryWarning** correctly)

Comment: I have added more than 20 UITabBarItem but I cannot choose all them because I cannot scroll them. Every touch I do in configuration view select an item instead of scroll them. Have you really tried to add more than 15 tabbar items?